# How to Keep Multiple Instances of the Same Gadget Separate

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-plugin

I have created a JIRA gadget. When I put only one instance of it on a dashboard, it's fine. When I put a second instance on the same dashboard, configure it to load different data, and then refresh the whole dashboard, I can see that they share most data -- as if they get their data from the server at almost the same time and then write to the same javascript variable and then render based on that variable.

When they render, they're mostly identical to each other when I know they should be totally different (I can see values that match instance A's configuration appearing in instance B).

Another way I can tell it's wrong is when I refresh each gadget separately, they display the correct data. But when I refresh the entire dashboard, they display mostly the same thing.

How do I keep these separate? One thought I had was to try the following:

1. Keep a thread-safe request counter on the server.
2. For each request, increment the counter and append the new value to the names of javascript variables in the velocity template.
3. When adding items to the context hash map, append the request counter to the keys so they match the javascript variables in step 2
4. The renderer takes the modified velocity template and the context hash map and produces something that refers to only its own request results.

But I'm having some trouble with step 2. I have the 'location' of the template file "/templates/gadgets/my-gadget.vm" -- it's not a real location in that there is no such file on the server at that path. The renderer expects the 'location' as an argument. I want to load /templates/gadgets/my-gadget.vm (wherever it actually is), write out a new /templates/gadgets/my-gadget..vm, and then pass this new location to the renderer... But /templates/gadgets/my-gadget.vm is not an ordinary file path. Where is it?

Or is there a better approach?

Note: nothing in the servlet is marked static or volatile -- everything in the servlet is instance-specific (and therefore request-specific ???) so the bleeding between requests is on the client side (see comments for discussion on whether this is correct and see the accepted answer for the tl;dr).

Comment: There is no need to increment variable names: JIRA gadgets are run in totally separate iframes and one gadget has no access to any of the variables, or anything else, from the other gadget. How are you persisting the configuration data that your user selects? Do you explicitly store the user-configured parameters anywhere on your own? (Can you post your gadget spec?)

Comment: Also, you mentioned that refreshing each gadget separately produces the correct data, but refreshing them together has them (mostly) display the same thing. Can you explain what you mean by "mostly"? I also see your edit mentioning that nothing in the servlet is static or volatile...but given the total separation of gadgets on the client side, this strongly suggests a server-side concurrency issue of some other sort. A good starting place is to log your servlet parameters when they come in (as provided by the gadget client), as well as the output the servlet produces.

Comment: The constructor for the servlet stores instance variables from values passed in as arguments for TemplateRenderer, UserManager, I18nResolver, JiraWebResourceManager, User, SearchService, ApplicationProperties ... and from ComponentAccessor it gets ProjectManager.  The gadget configuration gets passed in via the HttpServletRequest and values from it are stored as more instance variables.  A context hash map is created with values from the HttpServletRequest object, from instance variables, and from a computation. The renderer gets a common template, the context, and a writer from response obj.

Comment: "The gadget configuration gets passed in via the HttpServletRequest and values from it are stored as more instance variables." -- Your plugin only ever has one single copy of the servlet object (ie. it's not re-instantiated for every request). Anything you write to an instance variable will be shared between requests, and anything related to a specific request needs to be kept on the stack. Could that be it?

Comment: Sounds like the explanation. Logging shows the constructor only being called once and request #1 with its values, request #2 with its values and then the response for #1 and #2 are identical except for the request ID which I have as an atomic int counter. I need to learn how to keep something on the stack.

Comment: Great! I'll post this below as an answer then...please accept/upvote if it gets you where you need to be.

Comment: @ScottDudley you asked about how the gadgets were displaying *mostly* the same thing. I'm displaying bar charts and with my bug, most of the bars are identical. I suppose the one or two that are not are the result of a thread generating a response using data that's 'almost done' being overwritten by another thread?

Comment: I think my question was rendered moot by what we discovered with the instance variables; but basically, anything you put in an instance variable in the servlet object will be shared by every thread that is processing requests at the same time. Depending on which thread reads and writes which variable at what time, and considering how the threads get timesliced and/or scheduled on separate cores etc, the results will be nondeterministic (to say the least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you were storing values passed in from the HttpServletRequest as "instance variables" on the server side. The issue is that JIRA only ever instantiates a single copy of your servlet object, meaning that anything you write to an instance variable will be shared between requests. If both requests come in at the same time and they get interleaved, thread #1 will see data from thread #2 by accident, which is probably what happened.

The solution is to keep everything on the stack. For example, instead of writing to instance variables, just declare local variables inside your `service` method and leave everything there instead of at the class scope.

If you already have other functions in your servlet class that are using the instance variables, you can either modify them to receive the values passed over as parameters during the method call, or else refactor and move that code to another class that uses its own instance variables (but make sure you explicitly instantiate a new object of that class within `service()` every time you receive a request!).